# How to delete the records that has '?' in a file using sed

Tags: sed

How to delete the records that has '?' in the file ?

### Input file data

```
12345 Line1

?

34567 Line2

?

89101 Line3
```

### Expected Output

```
12345 Line1

34567 Line2

89101 Line3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you want to replace a blankline followed by a `?` symbol again followed blank line with  a single blank line. If so then try the below `perl` command.

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/\n\?\n//g' file
```

**Example:**

```
$ perl -0777 -pe 's/\n\?\n//g' file
12345 Line1

34567 Line2

89101 Line3
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sed '/?/d' yourfile
```

or

```
grep -v '?' yourfile
```

if you only wanted just a '?' and nothing else, do '^?$' instead of just the ?.